# Amend string / URL and iterate through list

Tags: python, string, list, function

I'm looking to scrape a certain table where the link is amendable with a certain year and week.

`URL = https://www.debestseller60.nl/200511#top`

I have two lists; one having years ranging between 2005 and now and one having all the week numbers in a year.

`years = list(range(2005, 2023))`

`weeks = list(range(1, 52))`

I tried amending the URL this way but that doesn't give me the right outcome.

`url = "url = "https://www.debestseller60.nl/{years}{weeks}#top"`

How would I be able to create a list of all these URLs that I can then use to then scrape through BeautifulSoup?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a list of URLs based on your lists of years and weeks, you can use nested list comprehensions in Python. Here's how you can do that:

```py
years = list(range(2005, 2023))
weeks = list(range(1, 53)) # Weeks should probably range from 1 to 53, since rarely there can be 53 instead of 52 weeks in a year

urls = [f"https://www.debestseller60.nl/{year}{week:02}#top" for year in years for week in weeks]
```

This will create a list of URLs with all the possible combinations of years and weeks. Note the `:02` in the f-string formatting for the week variable, which ensures that the week number is always two digits long, even for single-digit weeks (e.g., 01, 02, 03, etc.).

Now you can use this list of URLs to scrape data using BeautifulSoup. Here's a basic example of how to do that:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

        # Your scraping logic here

    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch data for URL: {url}")
```

This code will loop through the list of URLs, fetch the content using the requests library, and then create a BeautifulSoup object for each URL if the request is successful. You can then add your scraping logic within the loop to extract the data you need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Appreciate your help - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example how to iterate over years/months, construct the URL and use it in `requests`/`beautifulsoup`:

```py
base_url = 'https://www.debestseller60.nl/{year}{month}#top'

for year in range(2005, 2023):
    for month in range(1, 52):
        url = base_url.format(year=year, month=month)

        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        # ...
```

Comment: Appreciate this - thank you!

Comment: I got it to work (yay!). What's happening now is that it scrapes the data and stores it in a data frame... yet it only seems to keep the last date when saving to CSV instead of concatenating/unioning all data frames across multiple dates. Any thoughts?